# Proving $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} (1-x)^{r+1} \int_{1}^{\infty} s^r x^s ds = \int_{0}^{\infty} s^r e^{-s}ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

> Show that
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} (1-x)^{r+1} \int_{1}^{\infty} s^r x^s ds = \int_{0}^{\infty} s^r e^{-s}ds$$

I tried taking the limit inside the integral but that didn't work. I also used properties of gamma function, including the limit definition

$$ \Gamma (r+1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} s^r e^{-s} ds = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^{r+1} n!}{(r+1)(r+2)\ldots(r+n+1)} $$

and then tried to manipulate the limit in the RHS, but it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably it is $x\to 1^-,$ the left limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, typo. Corrected.

Comment: $x$ should be replaced by $r$ in the RHS of your last equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 < x < 1$, we have,

$\displaystyle I_{x} (r) = (1-x)^{r+1} \int_{1}^{\infty}s^r x^s ds$

Let $u = -s \log x$

$\displaystyle \implies I_{x} (r) = \left(\dfrac{1-x}{-\log x} \right)^{r+1}\int_{-\log x}^{\infty} u^r x^\frac{-u}{\log x} \ du$

$\displaystyle = \left(\dfrac{1-x}{-\log x} \right)^{r+1}\int_{-\log x}^{\infty}u^r \left(x^\frac{-1}{\log x}\right)^u du$

$\displaystyle = \left(\dfrac{1-x}{-\log x} \right)^{r+1}\int_{-\log x}^{\infty}u^r e^{-u} du$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^-} \left(\dfrac{(1-x)}{- \log x} \right) = 1$, we get,

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^-} I_{x} (r) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \left(\dfrac{(1-x)}{- \log x} \right)^{r+1} \times \lim_{x \to 1^-}\int_{-\log x}^{\infty}u^r e^{-u} du $

$\displaystyle = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^r e^{-u} du$

$\therefore \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} (1-x)^{r+1} \int_{1}^{\infty} s^r x^s ds = \int_{0}^{\infty} s^r e^{-s}ds = \Gamma (r+1) \ \ \square$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0<x<1.$ Let $x=e^{-y}.$ Then: $s^rx^s=s^re^{-ys}.$

Letting $t=sy $  $$\begin{align}\int_1^\infty s^rx^s\,ds&=y^{-1}\int_{y}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{y}\right)^re^{-t}\,dt\\
&=y^{-(1+r)}\int_{y}^\infty t^re^{-s}\,dt\end{align}$$

As $x\to 1^{-},$ we have $y\to 0^+.$ So, you get that you want:

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \left(1-e^{-y}\right)^{r+1}y^{-(1+r)}\int_y^{\infty} t^re^{-t}\,dt.$$

So you need $$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \left(\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}\right)^{r+1}=1.$$

This is true since since $\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}\to 1.$

Comment: Thanks @Martund

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: You're still doing the substitution wrongly. When $t=sy$, we have $ds=\frac{dt}{y}$, so your partial answer should be complete.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn’t edited it yet with your fix. The other edit was to start using $y$ earlier. @Martund